# writing gradle task extending from Test

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to write a custom plugin which should define his own test task. This task should have the properties of a common test task, but do some extra stuff.

My task class looks like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test

class MyTestTask extends Test {

    @TaskAction
    def intTest() {
        dosomething()
    }
}
```

My plugin class which should create this task looks like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project;

class JavaProjectPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.plugins.apply('java')
        project.task('myTest', type: MyTestTask)

        doMoreStuff()
    }
}
```

But when I try to execute a project applying this plugin, I get this Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:733)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:703)
    ... 232 more
```

Do I miss something, or do I have to do this completely different?

After buidling the plugin with gradle 1.9 I got this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.<init>()V
    at com.ibm.gradle.MyTestTask.<init>(MyTestTask.groovy)
    at com.ibm.gradle.MyTestTask_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:529)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:124)
    ... 218 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the answer from Bill Lin addresses this problem correctly. Like I said in the comment, it is not gradle 0.7, but gradle 1.12. Since they changed the constructor of Test class, you have to provide a constructor at least like this:

```
@Inject
public MyTestTask(ListenerManager listenerManager, StyledTextOutputFactory textOutputFactory, FileResolver fileResolver,
                Factory<WorkerProcessBuilder> processBuilderFactory, ActorFactory actorFactory, Instantiator instantiator,
                ProgressLoggerFactory progressLoggerFactory) {
    super(listenerManager, textOutputFactory, fileResolver, processBuilderFactory, actorFactory, instantiator, progressLoggerFactory )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check that your are using gradle 1.2 at runtime?
You may generate your plugin in gradle 1.12 but using it with a lower version at runtime

Comment: actually I have no idea how to execute on 1.2. I am executing this plugin with a wrapper (version 1.9) and I can't just change to another version.
The plugin are build with the gradle plugin for eclipse. I guess it is version 1.12

Comment: It seems you need to build your plugin in 1.9 otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I built it with 1.9 but now I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.<init>()V`

Comment: Could you provide the full stack-trace?  It seems something still wrong with version ...

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This NoSuchMethodError was caused by not such constructor for org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test. This empty constructor (take no parameters) was added in gradle 0.8. It seems your runtime gradle version is gradle 0.7 or earlier.  see http://www.gradle.org/docs/0.7/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html

This means you have to provide an empty constructor  for your MyTestTask which call Test constructor:

```
Test(Project project, java.lang.String name)
```

I strongly suggest you push for newer gradle version at runtime.

Comment: I don't realy get it. I build both the plugin and the project with a wrapper using the same gradle 1.9 distribution. How could one of them then use gralde 0.7 or what ever?

Comment: It seems the runtime gradle version is 0.7 or earlier. Could you please check that the wrapper was used?

Comment: Ok it really seems like there is a problem with the versions. But I still have no clue why gradle should use such an old version. I guess I made up this problem with the gradle plugin for eclipse from STS. And I have no idea where to change/set the gradle version for developing and building.

Comment: Ok I checked the newest API docu and found that the Test class has a constructor with parameters again. see http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html
This API hasn't changed until gradle 2.0. Since I do not want to use gradle 2.0 yet, do you know how to use the Test class with those parameter?